# How to load the content using ajax call and normal php call?

Tags: php, ajax

I have created jquery-ajax call for php page that creates content by selecting data from database based on the id it receives from the first page

the first page index.php have link person1 when I click on person1 it redirects through jquery to details page here is the code :

```
 $('.details').click(function() { 
        $("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
             var id = $(this).attr("id");
              $.ajax({  
                type: "GET",  
                url: "details.php",
                data:{pid:id},
                success: function(html){        
                    $("#persons").html(html).fadeIn(1000);

                }  
            }); 

                 return false;  
        });
```

The content will be loaded here in index.php file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns" id="persons" style="display:none" >

    </div>
</div>
```

the content of details page :

```
   <?

    if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
$id=(int)$_GET['pid'];
    $sql="select id, name,title,details,image,cat from persons  where id ='".$id."' order by name asc";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    if(list($id,$name,$title,$details,$image,$cat)=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
  ?>
    <h3><? echo $name;?></h3>
    <h5><? echo $title;?></h5>
    <p align="justify">
        <img alt="<? echo $name;?>" src="images/persons/<? echo $image?>" title="<? echo $name;?>" style="float:right; margin-left:15px;" />
        <? echo $details;?>
    </p>
    <?
    }
    }
?>
```

how to check if the page has been requested via ajax call or normal php call? and if it is not ajax call, load the content of details page normally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following variable:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
```

It should be 'xmlhttprequest' for AJAX requests.

However, you could simply add a parameter to the URL:

```
url: "details.php?thisisanajaxrequest=1",
```

And simply check the URL variable.

Comment: and how to load the content into div in case normal call not ajax ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by a "normal call".

This is how it looks like most of the time:  

 - you have a page that can be called from AJAX or simply by using its URL
 - the first thing in the code of the page is to check whether it is an AJAX call  
 - if it is an AJAX call, just serve the relevant content (BTW, this is usually something JSON encoded)  
 - if it is a regular call, render the page  

In your case, this would mean to render the whole page, while also filling up the DIV from PHP.

Comment: If you want to populate your div when the page is first loaded, just issue an ajax call at body onload, or you can just file_get_contents the URL.